# add() method in Vector faster than in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare the add method (for 1000 elements) in the class `Vector` and in the class `ArrayList`.

Why is the add method in `Vector` faster then add method in `ArrayList`?

Here is the code I am using to measure:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List v = new Vector();
    List l = new ArrayList();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        v.add(i);
    }
    long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("Vector: " + duration + " ns");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }
    duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("ArrayList: " + duration + " ns");
}
```

Comment: Did you compare the code? [ArrayList#add()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Vector#add()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Vector.java#Vector.add%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: import java.util.*;

public class prova {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List v = new Vector();
  List l = new ArrayList();
  
  long startTime=System.nanoTime();
  for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
   v.add(i);
  }
  long duration=System.nanoTime()-startTime;
  System.out.println("Vector: " + duration + " ns");
  
  startTime=System.nanoTime();
  for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
   l.add(i);
  }
  duration=System.nanoTime()-startTime;
  System.out.println("ArrayList: " + duration + " ns");

 }

}

Comment: Doing benchmarking is not simple as that you are doing. You need to take in account many factors (such as warmup, JIT optimizations, etc). Consider using a benchmark framework such as JMH to test.

Comment: I get `Vector: 305213 ns, ArrayList: 240066 ns` woth your code. These kinds of microbenchmarks are very unreliable.

Comment: please put it in the question

Comment: @Federica you better add this comment in your post, it easier to read then

Answer (score 1):

The results are probably distorted due to [JVM warmup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345999/avoid-jvm-warmup). After running the test few times I have obtained the following results:

```
1553108 [ns]   → Vector.add()
1420628 [ns]  → ArrayList.add()
```

The benchmark was conducted for 10000 insertions.

Comment: When I compile my code, I obtain different results: in my output, Vector seems faster than ArrayList! How is it possible? Thank you!!